# Local modules not mounting through Docker in K6

Tags: docker, k6

As part of my load test, within K6, I need to authenticate against AWS, which requires generating a JWT Token. This requires various local modules; aws-sdk, crypto-js to name a few.

These are located in the standard `./node_modules` folder.

I read that Docker, initially, doesn't know about the local directories and so they need to be mounted.

This is the command I currently use in order to achieve this:

```
docker-compose run -v $(pwd)/:/perf k6 run /perf/http_post.js
```

Within my `http_post.js` file, it has:

```
import requestPromise from 'request-promise';
http.get('https://google.com');
```

Which at the moment errors:

> ERRO[0024] GoError: Get https://request-promise?_k6=1: dial tcp:
>   lookup request-promise on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp
>   127.0.0.1:55571->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout

If I remove the import, it works.

Which then if I change it to:

```
import requestPromise from '../node_modules/request-promise/lib/rp.js';
```

appears to alleviate the issue, but then another similar issue crops up (which I think is down to the child dependencies the modules use):

> ERRO[0004] GoError: Get https://bluebird?_k6=1: dial tcp: lookup
>   bluebird on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

What can I do to resolve this? Ideally, I don't want to have to go through each dependency and its children to turn the module location into its absolute path.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not easily solved right now. There're two issues you're running into. Both stem from k6 being a distinct JS execution environment from Node.js.

The first is that Node.js libs in most cases can't be directly imported without first being ["browserified"](http://browserify.org/), as k6 doesn't support the core Node.js APIs, but does support the ES5 and ES6 standard library APIs (via https://github.com/zloirock/core-js). Many Node.js libs can't even be used after being browserified (in this case the Node.js [HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) APIs used by [request](https://github.com/request/request) is not supported).

The second is, as you alluded to, that k6 does not support the same dependency resolution algorithm that Node.js uses (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_all_together). So the import statement `import requestPromise from 'request-promise';` won't find `request-promise` in the usual places that Node.js would. When k6 doesn't find the dependency in the places where it looks on local disk it will try to retrieve it over the network, resulting in those "dial tcp: no such host" errors.

There is likely to be some more Node.js compatibility in the future, primarily around dependency resolution (https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/475), but for now it remains somewhat tricky to use Node.js libs beyond the more general ones.